# Derivation of quantum virial theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, virial-theorem

The quantum virial thoerem is derived by arguing that the left-hand-side of the following expression is zero for stationary/bound states:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\langle{\bf{r} \cdot \bf{p}}\rangle = \bigg\langle\frac{\bf{p}^2}{m}\bigg\rangle - \langle \bf{r} \cdot \nabla{V} \rangle
$$
In the classical case this follows from a consideration of the time average of this expression, which tends to $0$. Why is the same true, intuitively, in the quantum case?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem#In_quantum_mechanics). Hint: go to the Heisenberg picture.

Answer (score 1):

For *any* operator $O$, the expectation value in a stationary (eigen-) state $|\psi(t) \rangle $ is constant,
$$
\langle O \rangle = \langle \psi(t) | O | \psi(t) \rangle = \langle \psi(0) | e^{i E t} O e^{-i E t} | \psi(0) \rangle = e^{(i E - i E)t} \langle \psi(0) | O |  \psi(0) \rangle  =  \langle \psi(0) | O |  \psi(0) \rangle 
$$
where $E$ is the energy of that state.  Since this expectation value doesn't depend on time, the time derivative is identically 0.